# improfile's write equivalent

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB's [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/) there's the [`improfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/improfile.html) function that returns the intensity profile of an image from underneath a line defined by two points.

Is there a *writing* equivalent of this function? That is, I would like to pass two points (to specify a line) and a vector of pixel values to replace a bunch of pixels underneath the line.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429210/get-all-pixel-coordinates-of-a-vector-inside-a-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done basically what [Ghaul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426352/ghaul) suggested, but replaced `imline()` with manually finding underlying pixels. The advantage is that a figure is not shown which brings some speed benefits (~0.5s in my tests);

```
dist_euc = norm(p1 - p2);
n_pix = round(dist_euc*2);
step = (p1 - p2)/n_pix;
pix_coords = zeros(n_pix, 2);
for cp = 0:n_pix
    pix_coords(cp+1, :) = round(p2 + cp*step);
end
pix_inds = sub2ind(size(im), pix_coords(:,2), pix_coords(:,1));
pix_inds = unique(pix_inds);
im(pix_inds) = interpft(prof, length(pix_inds));
```

Answer (score 2):

I know an ugly way to do this. This is how:

Use imline to create a ROI consisting of you line. (Use imshow first.)

```
imshow(I,[])
H = imline(gca,[x1 y1; x2 y2]);
```

Create binary ROI from inline

```
BW = createMask(H);
```

Find the coordinates of the ROI

```
p = find(BW==1);
```

Insert your vector into image I along the line specified by the ROI

```
I(p) = v;
```

For this to work the length of vector v and the length of the ROI must be the same. This is not always easy. To fix it, interpolate your v vector to get the right size, that is, replace the last line with this

```
I(p) = interpft(v,length(p));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the source code for `improfile`? It uses `interp1` followed by `round` to obtain the indices of the profile points.

A simpler (and probably not as good) alternative is to use a simple parametric equation for the line and obtain the individual points along the line segment:

```
imageData =zeros(50,50);
endPoints =[ 2 3; 40 27];

numberOfInterpolationPoints = 50;
t=linspace(0,1,numberOfInterpolationPoints);

% x and y of the points along this line
x = 2 + t*( 40-2);
y = 3 + t*(27-3);

% Round them to obtain valid indices
profPoints = [x;y]';
profPoints = round(profPoints);

% Keep only unique numbers
profPoints = unique(profPoints,'rows');

% Convert to liner indices
profPointsInd = sub2ind(size(imageData),profPoints(:,1), profPoints(:,2));

imageData(profPointsInd) = 1;

imagesc(imageData);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something very similar in the end (see my answer below).